# Proper way to free allocated pointer on crash

Tags: c++, c

Imagine causing a segfault in C program which is common (and bad). Should I be aware about 'still reachable' pointers that were allocated during the runtime?

I googled about Valgrind's opinion on still reachable pointers (also read other related stackoverflow topics) and what I learned is that basically it's not a big problem and I don't have to worry about it. But I do.
In C++ it could be kinda fixed by using freeing destructor which will be always called according to standard.

```
void lose_definetly() {
  int * array = calloc(4,sizeof(int));
  array[3] = 1232;
}

void proper_free() {
  int * array = calloc(4,sizeof(int));
  array[3] = 1232;
  free(array);
}

void cause_segfault() {
  int * array = calloc(4,sizeof(int));
  array[-1232142144] = 1232;
  free(array);
}

int main() {
  lose_definetly();
  proper_free();
  cause_segfault();
  return 0;
}
```

Program output is expected segfault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Valgrind's report on leaks:

```
==134==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==134==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==134==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==134==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==134==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

So, please, suggest if I should care of this case and how can I aware myself aside from writing a proper code and pointers control. Is it possible to create a callback function on this case (or override interrupt signal)?

Comment: You should cure the segmentation fault, and if you have memory leaks you should fix them. It isnt' really necessary to free everything you have `malloc()`-ed before exiting, but doing so may reveal some surprising bugs ....

Comment: [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) [signal(SIGSEGV, ...)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) If you application crashes, why would you care to free the memory? The OS will do it for you anyway. Unless you don't intent to crash...

Comment: In case there is a crash, your program can't really be expected to clean up after itself, since it has ceased to behave predictably. The main reason why we do cleanup before returning to OS is not because the OS requires us to free the memory, but because it exposes any memory corruption bugs we might have related to pointers to allocated memory.

Comment: Why do you care about memory leaks if you're about to shutdown?  You don't know what state your pointers are in; and you may end up trying to free random memory.  The point of a seg fault is that it's all gone wrong, and it's time to terminate, not time to tidy up and be nice.

Comment: @Lundin is the idea of queue of allocated pointers that will be freed in overloaded sigsegv is too bad for this? Or it's just not needed at all?

Comment: @MaxVlasov *Everything* is 'too bad for this'. You have already encountered a SIGSEGV, which can only mean there is something severely wrong with your program. What you need to do is *fix it*. Not provide 1,000 crutches.

Comment: @MaxVlasov The point is that you can't know what problem the memory corruption caused, so you can't continue executing. This is the problem with RAM-based systems. If you had an embedded system with read-only flash, it would be another story. But then you wouldn't use dynamic allocation in the first place.

Comment: @MaxVlasov *queue of allocated pointers that will be freed in overloaded sigsegv*  You can't call `free()` in a signal handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process receives a segfault, it will be terminated, and the OS will release its allocated resources. There is no point in worrying about leaks at that point.

> In C++ it could be kinda fixed by using freeing destructor

No. Destructors are not executed upon abnormal termination.

What you can do is catch a segfault signal, but you are limited to using async signal safe functions. Functions dealing with memory allocation are not signal safe. If there are resources allocated by something other than the operating system (possibly on some remote system), then you can attempt to release them in the handler, but that can be challenging due to the limitations of async signal handlers.

Comment: It should be stated this answer applies to normal processes in typical general-purpose multi-user systems, since the operating system has overall control and management of the memory used by processes. In device drivers or kernel extensions in such systems or any software in some embedded systems, the answer could be different.

Comment: @EricPostpischil who's going to detect a segfault when there is no OS, nor segmented memory? I'm not familiar with recovering from bad state on embedded system. Would a soft reboot be out of question?

Comment: For a device driver, kernel panic is typical, I presume? (I guess a micro kernel might be recoverable from such violation, though)

Comment: I did not say there was no operating system. There can be some operating system. Recover from failure of a device driver or process might be to restart it, proceed without it, or reinitialize the system, and possibly other things.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to clean up after a crash of this type is a fool's errand. More than likely, the runtime environment will be too corrupt to permit recovery anyway and, worse, the corrupt environment may cause your `free` calls to have unexpected, possibly even harmful, results.

This is like trying to clean your room when your house is on fire. Just get out as quickly as you can before you get badly burned.

Comment: Lol'd at the analogy. Quick 'n' easy explanation though. Props!